# Are these files safe or likely to be problematic in future?

Tags: usb-drive

If filesystem corrupted on flash drive, and I transfer files to computer or another USB, how likely is it that there will be a problem with those files later on? Like corrupted files...

Comment: How do you ensure you get all the data correctly copied since the data is from unreliable source?

Comment: Have to open in read-only, see if files open w/o problem. After I copy them, what can I do to flash drive to fix filesystem, or whatever is the problem ? Don't want to try to fix USB until copy them over. Some files had "encoding" issues, making them seem like huge files. Also, as some copied, the number of files being transferred was stated as a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy files from a device with a corrupted filesystem, you might get valid files, or corrupted files. But the valid files won't "rot" over time once you have them stored in a functioning filesystem.

You should use `ddrescue` to recover your files, then wipe (or discard) the faulty flash drive.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the files are transferring, but the corrupt ones are making it difficult b/c so large and I have to find them and delete, etc. Many hours have past...